# Adding data to a password-protected Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a sheet with password. But I need to add some data from vba code. How can I do this? Maybe I can reset password, then add data and then set it again

```
 Me.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect 111

Me.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=111, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

When I use simple password, code works, but if I set pass: pass111111 - there is an error Wrong password

Comment: password is a string, not a number.

Comment: Use `Password:="111"` instead of `Password:=111`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy:

```
sub Protect_Sheet()
Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Unprotect Password:="Password"

'Do something 

Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Protect Password:="Password"

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, but it works only for simple password, for example : 111, But when I try pass111111 -there is an error

Comment: Why don't you do: Unprotect Password:=11111 (?)

Comment: Copy paste the code that I posted identically, replace the "Password" by 111111 and it guarantee it works. Well, I just did the same thing. If you add a string, put it between: " "

Comment: I think I know what's happening. You already set the password to 11111. When you are "Unprotect"ing it, you are using pass111111. Unprotect it first using the UI (or immediate window) using your old password.

Comment: I merely aimed at providing the basic syntax to help the OP figuring out why his original code didn't work. It can be used and customized any way preferred.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this code to protect your worksheet

```
Sub ProtectSheet()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="111111", _
    Contents:=True, userInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

Note the use of `userInterfaceOnly:=True`

When you use the Protect method with `UserInterfaceOnly` argument set to `True` as shown above then you protect the user interface but not macros. So you don't need to UnProtect the sheet to add data from macros. You can directly perform actions with it. For example

```
Sub ProtectSheet()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="111111", _
    Contents:=True, userInterfaceOnly:=True

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't know about `UserInterfaceOnly` - Handy. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set it to be protected with `Password = 111` You will have to unprotect with that password, you can then reprotect with a new password:

```
        Me.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="111"

        Me.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="pass111111", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

That's the only reason I can think of to explain this.